# Show Electron Windows Tray Icon on main taskbar, not under Show Hidden Icons

Tags: electron, system-tray, tray

I'm building an electron app and I realized that the tray icon on Windows does now appear on the main taskbar, but in the area that pops out when you click the upward arrow.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlzDG.png)

I see that Dropbox has theirs on the main taskbar and I know I can move mine on the main taskbar, but I would love to have it there by default.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same things, this is what worked for me:

```
const { Menu, Tray } = require('electron')

let tray = null
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  //add your path
  tray = new Tray(path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'src', 'assets', 'company.jpg'))
  const contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    { label: 'Item1', type: 'radio' },
    { label: 'Item2', type: 'radio' },
    { label: 'Item3', type: 'radio', checked: true },
    { label: 'Item4', type: 'radio' }
  ])
  tray.setToolTip('This is my application.')
  tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu)
})
```

hope It helps, and make sure you use the app.getAppPath() otherwise it will run on your electron build but won't work on win. package

Comment: nope, the answer was not how to create a tray, but rather how to pin it in the main taskbar, not in the hidden section